# swapping between Hard drives with OS in a laptop

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd, hardware-detection

I'm about to do some tinkering/experimentation with my laptop and looking for some options to keep my system safe from any wrongdoings that I may trigger.

Therefore, is it possible to take out my present and only SSD from my laptop and replace it with a blank old SSD and install another OS on it? When I'm done tinkering or when I mess up, I would just swap the SSD's and boot up like always without any problems.

I know you can do this also with a virtual machine but my budget laptop can't handle that load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Therefore, is it possible to take out my present and only SSD from my
> laptop and replace it with a blank old SSD and install another OS on
> it.

Yes, you can do this. You can install Windows 10 again as Windows 10 will activate properly because you are just changing system drives.

After you have finished experimenting, you can put the original drive back.